# VBA Lotus Notes MIME attached PDF cannot be displayed

Tags: vba, encoding, lotus-notes, mime, email-headers

I had some issues with code that I wrote to send 2 attachments via VBA, with some help I figured out how to use MIME to attach 2 different attachments. However now the issue seems to be that the HTML attaches as body fine but the PDF that I want as an attachment doesn't open and errors.

I sent a normal PDF attachment to see what Headers are produced to see if I could solve it. They do seem to differ but I'm not sure how I would achieve the same headers in code as any changes don't seem to produce the desired output in VBA.

Normal email headers for attachment -

--=*alternative 002FD1AF802588B4*=--
--=*mixed 002FD1AF802588B4*=
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="Import Declaration Report (GGRFXT2208000000001019).pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Import Declaration Report (GGRFXT2208000000001019).pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

My automated send headers -

--==IFJRGLKFGIR38462UHRUHIHD
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename=Import Declaration Report (GGRFXT2208000000001019).pdf

--==IFJRGLKFGIR38462UHRUHIHD--

How in the hell do I get something similar, even though I have created a header for encoding it doesn't seem to do anything and I would really like to work this out.

```
Public Sub COM_Email_Send()

Dim NSession As Object
Dim NMailDb As Object
Dim NDocument As Object
Dim NBody As Object
Dim NChild As Object
Dim Nstream As Object
Dim Header As Object
Dim HeaderChild As Object
Dim NParent As Object
Dim NMime As Object

Dim i As Long
Dim Row As Long
Dim Recipient As String
Dim File As String
Dim attachmentFile As String
Dim Data As String
Dim AttachedOb As Object
Dim EmbedOb As Object
Dim NHeader As Object
Dim strFileType As Variant
Dim MIMEDoc As Object

Set NSession = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
Call NSession.Initialize("password")

Set NMailDb = NSession.GetDatabase("Directory", "Server")
If Not NMailDb.IsOpen = True Then
Call NMailDb.Open
End If

    Row = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To Row
    
    Recipient = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
    
    If Recipient <> "" Then
    
    
    File = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    
    attachmentFile = "Directory" & File
    
    Data = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    
    NSession.ConvertMIME = False
    
    Set Nstream = NSession.CreateStream
    Set NDocument = NMailDb.CreateDocument
    
    
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("Form", "Memo")
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("SendTo", Recipient)
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("Subject", "Please see your clearance documents attached " & Data)
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("Sender", "noreply@Dachser.com")
    
    
    Set NMime = NDocument.CreateMIMEEntity("Body")
    Set NParent = NMime.CreateParentEntity
    
    
    Call Nstream.Open("Directory")
    
    Set MIMEDoc = NParent.CreateChildEntity()
    Call Nstream.WriteText(strBody)
    Call MIMEDoc.SetContentFromText(Nstream, "text/html;charset=iso-8859-1", 1725)
    Call Nstream.Close
    Call Nstream.Truncate
    
    
    Set MIMEDoc = NParent.CreateChildEntity()
    
    Set HeaderChild = MIMEDoc.Createheader("Content-Disposition")
    Call HeaderChild.SetHeaderVal("attachment; filename=" & File)
    
    Set HeaderChild = MIMEDoc.Createheader("Content-Type")
    Call HeaderChild.SetHeaderVal("application/pdf")
    
    Set Nstream = NSession.CreateStream()
    
    If Not Nstream.Open("Directory", "binary") Then
    MsgBox ("Open Failed")
    End If
    
    
    Call MIMEDoc.SetContentFromBytes(Nstream, "application/pdf", 1727)
    
    
    
    Call Nstream.Close
    Call Nstream.Truncate
    
    NDocument.savemessageonsend = True
    
    Call NDocument.replaceitemvalue("PostedDate", Now())
    
    
    Call NDocument.Send(False)
    

    Set NDocument = Nothing
    Set Nstream = Nothing
    
    End If
    Next i
    
NSession.ConvertMIME = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT

It looks like the `SetContentFromBytes` is over-writting the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` from `ENC_BASE64` to `ENC_NONE` since `SetContentFromBytes` is supposed to set Encoding, I guess the question is how do I set BASE64 Encoding in `SetContentFromBytes` as the above declaration doesn't work (Only other way I found was `Domino.MIME_ENCODING.ENC_BASE64` which drops an error)??

***EDIT

Solved that issue by declaring it as the number, PDF still doesn't open however.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so VBA only takes the number for encoding and not what is stated in the Lotus Notes Documentation. And also instead of Application/pdf as I had first thought it ended up being Application/octet-stream. In addition octet-stream isn't base 64, its binary so declaring it as `Call MIMEDoc.SetContentFromBytes(Nstream, "application/octet-stream", 1730)` in the end solved it.

Comment: There's a .LSS file containing the constant declarations for things like MIME_ENCODING.ENC_BASE64. It's part of the Notes client install, but even in LotusScript code you have to explicitly include it. The doc consistently fails to mention this. In the case of VBA, you typically wouldn't even have that file available to include.